# Getting elements of the array MySQLi + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Trying to get array from using MySQLi and PHP, so that I could work with each element of the array (like `$array[0]`, `array[1]`)

```
$titlesquery = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = ?");
$titlesquery->bind_param('i', $id);
$titlesquery->execute();
$titlesquery->bind_result($returned_title);
$json = $titlesquery->fetch($returned_title, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json);
```

This doesn't work. I get such warning:

> mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 2 given

If it helps, just `$titlesquery->fetch();` works fine but I get not a kind of array(?) structure, just single element for that column. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what exactly says on the error message, it needs no parameters:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

> bool mysqli_stmt::fetch ( void )

```
$titlesquery->bind_result($returned_title);
$titlesquery->fetch();
$json = array('title' => $returned_title);
```

After you have invoked `->bind_result()`, this already binds results from your prepared statement.

If you want an array row fetching and this is available to you (needs mysqlnd), use `->get_result()` instead.

```
$titlesquery = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = ?");
$titlesquery->bind_param('i', $id);
$titlesquery->execute();

$result = $titlesquery->get_result();

$json = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: @Vinand if you have used `->bind_result()`, then you should use the bound variable you chosed, if you want an array row then use `->get_result()` if this is available to you, i have added this also above

Comment: I get an error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Comment: oh, it was my mistake. but now I get " PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()"

Comment: @Vinand when you used `->bind_result()`, with it inside the bound variable, in this case `$returned_title`, it will hold the value of that particular column, when you use `->get_result()` then `->fetch_assoc()`, you'll get an array row set in this case `Array( [title] => whatever title is id )`

Comment: sorry, didn't notice "needs mysqlnd".

Comment: @Vinand most likely you don't have `mysqlnd` driver in your environment

Comment: @Vinand by the way, if you're expecting multiple rows, you'll need to setup a loop `while($titlesquery->fetch()) { // codes here }`, but i think since its an ID (`id = ?`) and this is unique, then this setup should suffice